# Freemarker variable only getting last value instead of all

Tags: loops, variables, freemarker

Im trying to save a some values into a variable.

Im iterating over a list and I want to save the object if it is a Description

```
              <#if item[prop].value?starts_with("Description:")>
                  <#assign description = item[prop].value>
              </#if>
```

Then I try to create a table for this Description Items.

```
  <#if description?length gt 0>
     <#list description as desc>
        <table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 0px;">
           <tr>
              <td><strong>${desc?replace('&', '&amp;')?replace('\n', '<br/>')}</strong></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </#list>
  </#if>
```

The problem is that I'm only getting the last Description value instead of all the Descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

So it I cannot see the rest of your code but it appears that you are overwriting the value of description for every iteration in the loop.
If you want to iterate over the descriptions after so you can print them you will need a array or json. Something like:

```
<#assign x = []> <#-- create the array -->
<#assign x = x + [ "popo" ] /> <#-- add to it -->
```

One thig I would say is that you can really just create the description table WHILE you iterate over the initial list and be done with it?

ps. you may want to put the <#list> element around the  tags instead of duplicating the whole table...

** *warning: all code was written on the fly and is untested. use the concepts don't copy paste.*